# VBA - Loop will not increment by one each time in ID column

Tags: excel, vba, loops

In my VBA code, I am attempting to do the following:

1. Set the Active Cell to C11
2. Add the number 1 to an `id`
3. Prompt the user for a name and enter that in the cell to the right
4. Go to the next row & repeat.

However, the number that is entered is another one, not a 2, 3, 4....

Instead, I get the following:

```
1    Name 1
1    Name 2
1    Name 3
```

and I want:

```
1    Name 1
2    Name 2
3    Name 3
```

Here is the code, what am I missing?

```
Sub AddToSheet()
Dim id As Integer
Dim name As String

Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
ActiveCell.Range("C11").Select
For Each mycell In Range("C11:C20")

id = mycell.Select
ActiveCell.Value = 1
id = id + 1

name = mycell.Offset(0, 1).Select
name = InputBox("what is the film?")
ActiveCell.Value = name
Next mycell
End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to read [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for help formatting your post to make it more readable.

Comment: Your problem is in `ActiveCell.Value = 1`.  I think you actually want Your problem is in `ActiveCell.Value = id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not what you're missing, it's what you are getting wrong - some pointers:

1) There is rarely (dare I say, never) a need to use `.Select` in Excel VBA, you can access an object's properties directly without selecting the actual object. This is generally considered bad practice.

2) `id = mycell.Select` is not a valid statement, the .Select method merely sets focus to an object(s) it is not used to return a value.

3) `ActiveCell.Value = 1` <-- This is where you are going wrong as far as your question is concerned

4) Your code increments the value of `id` with each loop, but you do not actually use this value for anything - another hint at why it's not working as you expected.

5) Try and use indentation on your code, this will make it much easier for you (and others) to follow the logic of your code and help to ensure you have closed all 'block' statements.

Try this code instead:

```
Sub AddToSheet()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 11 To 20
   Range("C" & i & ":D" & i).Value = Array(i - 10, InputBox("What is the film?"))
Next i

End Sub
```

This accesses the `.Value` method of the `Range` object without actually selecting or activating it, and so we skip a couple of lines of code straight away. Secondly -  I've used an `Array` to assign the values so that we can do it all in one line of code - this is nothing groundbreaking and you won't see any difference in speed/performance but it's hopefully something for you to look at and possibly manipulate for your own uses in the future.

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Please could you explain the purpose of the colon before the D (":D"), Thanks

Comment: Sure, the `Range()` method accepts a string argument to refer to a range - so in the same way you could write "C1:D1" in a formula, you could use `Range("C1:D1")` in VBA. Now, because the row number is assigned to `i` we need to incorporate this into our string, so if for example `i = 5` then `"C" & i & ":D" & i` is the same as "C5:D5". There are different ways of passing this argument to a range method - this is just my preference, and just happens to suit this scenario. Which way you choose to do it will depend on the problem at hand and the logic of your code. Hope that helps.